# Golang, access denied when saving to .txt file

Tags: windows, file, go, file-permissions

I'm starting with golang and I'm trying to save some text into a file with os.WriteFile function.
When I'm saving it into a file with .txt file I get access denied error:

```
err := os.WriteFile("tex3.txt", []byte("text text text"), 0644)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

When I'm saving it into a file without the text extension - it works fine:

```
err := os.WriteFile("textFile", []byte("text text text"), 0644)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

I have tried the example from the [os documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/os#Mkdir) of Mkdir (unrelated, but it has .txt file extension). The code was:

```
err := os.Mkdir("testdir", 0750)
if err != nil && !os.IsExist(err) {
    panic(err)
}
err = os.WriteFile("testdir/testfile.txt", []byte("Hello, Gophers!"), 0660)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

It had no problems creating the folder, but I got access denied again for the text file.

I'm working with vscode. I've tried to open it in admin permissions, I've tried to run it with powershell and with gitbash. I've tried to create the file in and out of folders.

If it's a .txt extension I always get the access denied error. Without the extension it works.
How can I save to a text file using the os.WriteFile function?

Comment: What does `err` says?

Comment: does the file *exist* already ? i.e. open file pointer / file blocked by some clever Windows app ?

Comment: @FObersteiner Thanks!  The "clever" app was my anti virus. I disabled it and it worked. Just to clarify the file did not exist and the error itself was
 "panic: open textFile.txt: Access is denied".
Please add your comment as an answer so I can mark it as accepted

Comment: AV is a thing to look out for. That is, it can produce various problems aside from (or related to) denied permissions. For example I never experienced those, but had serious problems compiling go code in the first place on my Win machine. Bottom line is, very hard to generalize I think. Too "broad" for an answer, fine as a comment  :)